# Bootstrap 3 Typeahead Ajax search using php mysql function

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead

I'm trying to move a small `PHP+Mysql` project to `POO` using `TBootstrap` as `CSS framework`. For This project I'm trying to implemment an `autosuggest/complete` feature with `Typeahead` in mind. The thing is I don't have any idea how to use my `mysql query` with the `js` part. I been following some examples like this with no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //JS

            $('#product_name').typeahead({
                name: 'product_name',
                remote: '/myproject/core/app/model/ProductData.php?go=%p'

            });

        })

//MYSQL SEARCH
    public static function getsearch($p){
        $sql = "select * from products where descr like '%$p%' or name like '%$p%' or id like '%$p%'";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new ProductData());
    }


//PHP TO DISPLAY RESULTS IN HTML DATA
        $go=="name"){ $search=$_GET["product_name"];
        $products = ProductData::getLike($search);
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these:

**JS part**

```
 $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
      source:function (query,process) {
          return $.get('search.php',{query:query},function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              data = $.parseJSON(data);
              return process(data)
          });
     }
 });
```

**php part**

```
<?php
 $conn = "php db connection"
 $query = $_GET['query'];
 $array = array();

 $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from "your table here" where "column to search in" LIKE '%{$query}%'");

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row['column to return'];
 }
 echo json_encode($array);
?>
```